# Numerically sum aproximation$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^k (-1)^k k!}{\zeta (k+2)}$

Tags: calculus

How it is possible to sum the following series
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^k (-1)^k k!}{\zeta (k+2)}\approx0.21400901875221914$$ 
where the denominator is the Zeta function I tried Borel resummation but it did not work
And also it is possible to show that
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^k (-1)^k k!}{\zeta (k+2)^2}\approx 0.08605112650632883$$
the method used by  user90369 is good but need meny sum for example  to calculate
$$ \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^k (-1)^k k!}{\zeta (k+2)^4}\approx -0.00127522$$ need for Sum $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }$$ wo it is possible
somebody voted to close the question , but  user90369 has try to contribuit , it a pity

Comment: Yes divege in the Abel sense but do not Regularization Borel Summation

Comment: Using my answer below we get $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^k k!}{\zeta(k+2)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{\mu(j)\mu(n-j+1)}{j(n-j+1)}e^{j(n-j+1)/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{j(n-j+1)}{2}) \,$ .

Comment: Thanks it is works althought a little slowly

Comment: You are welcome. Yes: It's very slowly. You can check if it helps to use $\,\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\sum\limits_{v=1}^k {\binom {k}{v}} a_v\,$ .

Comment: But  user90369 the euler method do not work for the serie above

Comment: No problem, it was only a try. :-) What you need is a fast converging series for $\,1/\zeta(s)\,$ or better for $\,1/\zeta(s)^n\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We use analytical continuation here.*

$\Gamma(a,x)\,$ is the incomplete gamma function.

$\mu(n)\,$ is the Möbius function.

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^k k!}{\zeta(k+2)}= \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2x)^k}{\zeta(k+2)}dx= \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-2x)^k \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+2}} dx = $

$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^2} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-2x}{n}\right)^k dx =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{n+2x} dx =\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} e^{n/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{n}{2})$

where $\,\displaystyle e^x\Gamma(0,x)\,$ is positive and strictly monotone decreasing for $\,x>0\,$ .

An approximation, e.g.: $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{1000} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} e^{n/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{n}{2}) = 0.2140138...$

---

*Note:*

With $\enspace\displaystyle 0<\frac{1}{2}e^{x/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{x}{2})<\frac{1}{x}\enspace$ for $\, x>0 \,$ follows:

$\displaystyle 0 < \frac{1}{2} |\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} e^{n/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{n}{2})| < \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} e^{n/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{n}{2}) < \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

It's $\,\,\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} e^{n/2}\Gamma(0,\frac{n}{2}) \approx 0.9186\,$ .